# Corda Node deployment on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, blockchain, corda

I am following [this](https://docs.corda.r3.com/node-cloud.html) tutorial for deploying a node on aws using aws Corda AMI.

But after the registration step,

( `java -jar corda.jar initial-registration -p PASSWORD_FOR_NETWORK_ROOT_TRUSTORE`),

its throwing this error:

> [ERROR] 10:14:31+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke -
>   Exception during node startup: Network root trust store path:
>   '/opt/corda/4.0/certificates/network-root-truststore.jks' doesn't
>   exist [errorCode=szfwpy,
>   moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.0/szfwpy]

It seems like, it is not able to find network-root-truststore.

1. Can someone tell me where can we get this certificate from? I copied three certificates from an existing cordapp but it did not have network truststore.
2. Is there any proper resource for deploying the cordapp on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact a Corda network operator you plan to connect your node to and get information about Doorman (Identity Operator) and Network Map, as well as the Network Root Truststore file. The lack of the later is the reason of the issue you see.